# Laptop screen stops turning on at times unless

Tags: laptop, lcd, laptop-repair

I have a Metabox Clevo P965RE. It was recently dropped and the screen has a small dent in the corner. The LCD panel itself sustained no damage but there is a small dent. I usually have this laptop connected to a monitor via HDMI and it outputs in full HD just fine. But I do have an issue.

Everytime I use the laptop without a monitor, at times the LCD outputs just fine. At other times, the LCD flickers from black to a dark green and unless I close and then open the laptop, the screen sometimes outputs. Also, I've noticed that after sleeping, the screen at times refuses to turn on unless I completely restart the laptop. I have reinstalled display drivers and reinstalled the OS but no luck. What's worse is at one point, I plugged in the laptop into an external display because the LCD refused to turn on and Windows couldn't detect the LCD and only detected the external display. I know this can't be a GPU problem because it is working fine. What is going on and should I replace the LCD? Thank you very much.

Comment: if the issue started after the computer has been dropped, then yes, you might need to change your monitor. I don't think we could say a definite answer without looking your computer, just bring it to a professional to check it.

Comment: Your LCD panel is damaged. Just because it doesn't look damaged doesn't mean it isn't. Take it to a computer store.

Comment: I am planning to buy a new LCD for this model. I just wasn't sure because I was also told that it could be the GPU but I highly doubt that

Comment: Dropping it hard enough to dent it apparently caused some type of physical damage, but it could potentially be things other than the screen, itself.  You've already ruled out some of the things that could have been affected, but it needs diagnostics and a check for things like internal ribbon cables and connectors before doing an expensive screen replacement.  But it's a job for the repair shop.

Comment: Right. I will open the screen and check the cables since I think the connector is near the dented part according to the diagrams. If I can't replace the wire, I will definitely take the laptop to be repaired to avoid damaging it further.